# Optimizing JSON parsing - fetching name associated with ID

Tags: android, json

To give you an overview of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to access the server as little as possible for efficiency reasons. I thought I had this taken care of with the if-elseif-else block I had, but it still takes a larger chunk of time than I'd like. Is there any way this could be improved? In its current form, it is taking upwards of 2 minutes to go through this section. I would obviously like it to be as quick as possible.

When returning exclusively the runeId number from the JSON, it is instant. What I need to do however, is retrieve the name associated with that ID and return that. I have done a traceview on the section of code and included it below. I'm not sure how to read it, but I am sure the section at fault is my method of getting the name from the id (getRuneInfo).

Ultimately, what I'd like to do is store this information locally on the device, that way, over time, it wouldn't have to access the server, as the id-name pair would be stored locally, but I am unsure how to do this.

Traceview File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fc6kdk35wackwr/RuneLoop.trace

The loop:

```
// Loop through pages, page names stored in string array
for (int i = 0; i < rune.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = rune.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray slots = c.getJSONArray(TAG_SLOTS);
    name[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

    // This loop is where the slowdown is. Before I added this
    // the code ran very quickly. 
    for (int x = 0; x < 27; x++) {
        JSONObject s = slots.getJSONObject(x);

        if (Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID)).equals(prevId)) {
            runesArray[i][x] = runesArray[i][x - 1];
            prevId = Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID));
        } else if (Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID)).equals(runeIdArray[Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID))]))
            runesArray[i][x] = runeIdArray[Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID))];

        else
            // I believe the slowdown stems specifically from this
            runesArray[i][x] = getStaticData.getRuneInfo(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID));
            runeIdArray[Integer.valueOf(s.getString(TAG_RUNEID))] = runesArray[i][x];
    }
```

getRuneInfo Method:

```
public String getRuneInfo(String runeId) {
        String name = null;
        try {
            name = new GetRunes()
                    .execute(runeId)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return name;
    }
```

The else statement calls getRuneInfo, which starts this. I believe all the fetching is slowing it down.
GetRunes:

```
public static class GetRunes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String[] runeId) {
            String url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/rune/" +  runeId[0] + "?api_key=" + api_key;
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject runeInfo = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            String name = null;
            try {
                name = runeInfo.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is not very clear to me. seems interesting though! can you clearly point where the routine takes 2 minutes to complete, and where you need to get the name associated to the id?

Comment: @rupps Absolutely! Give me a minute to edit my main post. 
EDIT: Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you are doing, seems like 27 requests are being sent to the server, so this obviously takes time.

The requests are probably run serially, that is, one will start when the other finishes. You can save some time by enabling parallel execution like this:

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).
```

However, there are limits for how many tasks you can execute in parallel, and you will have to adapt your code a little for parallel execution. I am afraid that, if you need those 27 requests, not much can be done besides this.

Regarding your second question, it's obvious you need to store the requests locally. The easiest thing you can do is, in `GetRunes`, save every received JSON to a file in the sdcard, that's pretty straightforward, and then, also in `getRunes`, check if you have such file already downloaded. This way, it may take 2 minutes to download all your runes, but you'd need to do this only once. Once all the files are stored in the sdcard, execution will be nearly instantaneous.

I post here one routine I use to cache stuff, for your inspiration... basically I call it with an URL and that URL is downloaded to the sdcard, and stored in a filename that is the md5 hash of the url. So before downloading, I just check if the md5 of the requested url exists in the cache, and if it does, I read the file from the sdcard rather than downloading it.

```
private static boolean cache_url(Context context, String fileurl) throws DeviceNotOnlineException {

        try { 
               File cacheDir=new File(context.getCacheDir(),"url_cache");

            ensureOnline();

            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();

            File f=new File(cacheDir, md5(fileurl));
            URL url = new URL(fileurl); 

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);

            byte data[] = new byte[16384];
            int count=0;

            if (Conf.LOG_ON) Log.v(TAG, "Caching "+fileurl+" into "+f.getAbsolutePath());

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            if (Conf.LOG_ON) Log.e(TAG, "WARNING: FILE NOT FOUND! "+f.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (Conf.LOG_ON) e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about saving the data locally, and access it each time the app runs? 

Also, something I noticed while messing with my app was that when the screen changed orientation, it would start the 27 requests again. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: in getRunes, after getJSONfromURL save the whole JSON to a file, and also in getRunes, befor getJSONFromURL check if you have a saved verison

Comment: Thank you. My confusion was that I thought that you couldn't deal with Strings and Shared Preferences.

Comment: nah SharedPrefereces is meant to store small stuff. If you store too much it will slow the application start a lot. Its much better to directly save the file, you can save a raw json, images, whatever, and then load them very fast. There's no limit on how much stuff you can save -besides the sdcard capacity, of course!-

Comment: Just curious, and kind of just bouncing ideas around. If I could return all id's and names in one JSON and store that JSON, and then access it locally whenever needed, that would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: absolutely, if the JSON is reasonably sized it will probably be 27 times faster, the overhead of a network request is huge compared to the actual data processing time. Talking about local files, as they load very fast, there won't be that much difference, although only if that one combined file is huge you may prefer storing parts of it separately.

Comment: The JSON would be just about 3000 lines, and it works out to be 89KB. Would you consider that to be too large to store in one part?